# What does "kallocratic" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was reading [this n+1 article](https://nplusonemag.com/issue-17/politics/the-drone-philosopher/) and it uses the word "kallocratic" in this context:

> ... ascending Diotima’s ladder from the lower rung of desire for the sun-kissed body of the swimsuit model to the kallocratic worldview of beautiful actions based on knowledge of the eternal and beautiful forms ...

A Google search of the word only returns the article (and presumably now this question too).

Comment: You might also search alternative forms and spellings: kallocracy, callocracy, callocratic. Those return a book and some more articles.

Comment: Or my personal favorite: [callipygian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callipygian) - "possessing a beautiful butt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "rule by beauty" because Greek [κάλλος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82) (*kallos*) means "beauty". The OED has it as being the first etymon of the similarly spelled *kalloscope* for example and it's also part of [Kallipolis/Callipolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callipolis) (spelled in the more typical way, with an I), meaning "beautiful city" in Greek.